# delete a row after comparing specific values with other rows in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this ( SQL SERVER )

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       George   A       B       ++
2       Alex     B       B       aa
2       Alex     B       B       ++
```

now the second and the third rows have almost same values except in  col5. in this case I want to delete one of them (I want to be able to decide which row from both of them I want to delete) like the one with value ++ so the table should look like this:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       Goerge   A       B       ++
2       Alex     B       B       aa
```

How can that be achieved?

Comment: What criteria determine that ++ goes and aa stays? is it always the literal value ++ that gets deleted?

Comment: You need to define the criteria for a "duplicate". You said they are almost the same but you need to define this. And then you need to decide the rule for which row to delete.

Comment: the criteria could be everything. in my little example its in the col5. like if there is two rows that have the same value in col1 but different values in col5 then delete the one (row) that has the value ++ in the col5 and show in the result table only the row that doesnt have this value. but only of there is two rows that have same value in col1. there will be rows that have the value ++ in the col5 but no other rows with same values in col1 and in this case this row should stay in the result table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CTE with ROW_NUMBER() to find (and delete) your duplicates

```
WITH CTE_Dup AS 
(
   SELECT *
   , ROW_NUMBER OVER() PARTITION BY (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 ORDER BY Col5) RN
   -- change ORDER BY criteria to make sure row you want to keep is 1st
 FROM YourTable
)
DELETE --Try SELECT * to check before actually deleting
FROM CTE_Dup WHERE RN>1
```

Comment: I think it would be more general to change the last filter to WHERE RN=1, so if there is the record exists more than twice, the resulting dataset would not be duplicate either

Comment: @pcofre: If there are multiple rows, RN=1 would delete only one of them leaving duplicates again. Deleting where RN>1 deletes all the multiple rows leaving only one.

Comment: You are right. I thought you were performing a SELECT after the CTE

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear the logic you want here for determining which row is a "duplicate" but this example should show you a pretty straight forward way of handling this kind of thing.

```
declare @Something table
(
    col1 int
    , col2 varchar(10)
    , col3 char(1)
    , col4 char(1)
    , col5 char(2)
)

insert @Something
values
(1, 'Goerge', 'A', 'B', '++')
, (2, 'Alex', 'B', 'B', 'aa')
, (2, 'Alex', 'B', 'B', '++')
;

with SortedValues as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col1 order by col5 desc) as RowNum
    from @Something
)

delete SortedValues
where RowNum > 1

select *
from @Something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query. I grouped the columns and get the count of that and handled the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Query execution with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR (20), col3  VARCHAR (20), col4 VARCHAR (20), col5 VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES
(1, 'Goerge', 'A', 'B', '++'),
(2, 'Alex', 'B', 'B', 'aa'),
(2, 'Alex', 'B', 'B', '++');

SELECT * INTO #tmpResults FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  col1, col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY col1 ) AS CCnt
    FROM @TestTable
) a

SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM #tmpResults WHERE Ccnt = 1 AND Col5 = '++'
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM #tmpResults WHERE Ccnt > 1 AND Col5 <> '++';

DROP TABLE #tmpResults
```

**Output:**

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
------------------------------------
1       Goerge  A       B       ++
2       Alex    B       B       aa
```